# How to tell which advertiser is a commission from in CommissionJunction.com?

Tags: affiliate

I recently joined CommissionJunction.com and I signed up for different advertisers. The problem in reporting is that it shows the commissions and leads, but not who the lead is from.

Is there a way to determine which of the links that I used is responsible for the commission?

Answer (score 1):

You can view the commission performance of each link. Here are the steps:

1. Log into the CJ account manager and click on the **Run Reports** tab.
2. Click on the **Performance Reports** tab.
3. Select **Performance by Link ID**.
4. Select to run the report for only one of the sites you have listed in your account or leave the selection as **All Web Sites**.
5. Select your time frame and click **Generate Report**.